# What's the point of a static method that returns an instance of the class it's a part of?

Tags: php, class, static, singleton

Sometimes when I look at code other people have written I see something like the following:

```
<?php

namespace sys\database;

class Statistics {

    public function __construct() {
        // Database statistics are gathered here using
        // private methods of the class and then set to
        // class properties
    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        return new \sys\database\Statistics();
    }

    // ...

}
```

So the static function `getInstance()` simply returns an object of the class it belongs to. Then, somewhere else in the code I come across this:

```
$stats = \sys\database\Statistics::getInstance();
```

Which simply sets `$stats` to an instance of the `Statistics` object, ready for its class properties to be accessed to get various database statistics.

I was wondering why it was done this way as opposed to just using `$stats = new \sys\database\Statistics();`. At the end of the day, all the logic to gather statistics is in the constructor and the `getInstance()` method doesn't do anything other than returning a new object.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Usually, it's a way to ensure you get only one instance of a singleton class. That involves blocking access to the constructor by making it private, and having a static property that initializes this instance before returning it within `getInstance()`, all of which is strangely missing from this particular class. As it is written, it is indeed redundant in favor of just calling `new` directly.

Comment: Typically you'd see this in the case of the singleton pattern

Comment: I think generally an instance retrieval method is supposed to save resources by getting the instance the existing runtime may have already created.

Comment: Well the main point usually of creating function called getInstance is  creating the singleton object. Oh you are fast typers :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is supposed to be an implementation of the Singleton pattern: http://www.oodesign.com/singleton-pattern.html

The pattern is used to never allow more than one instance of the class to be created.

However, there are a couple of flaws with the implementation you provided: the constructor should be private, and there should be a single private static instance of the class, returned every time the `getInstance` method is called.

Comment: Ah! That makes a lot more sense now. I did think the `getInstance` method was missing something. I'll accept your answer in a few minutes when it lets me :)

Answer (score 2):

This is supposed to be an implementation of the Singleton pattern, which is a term used to describe a class which can only exist once for run-time.

It seems the implementation you have is flawed however because:

1. there is no check to see if the class exists yet and
2. code can create multiple instances by calling the constructor directly (it should be made private)

Answer (score 0):

That's a [bad] implementation of the [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

As a rule of thumb, you should avoid such pattern in favour of more convenient [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), for instance.

Comment: In most of the cases there's no good implementation of the singleton pattern :D sorry for the offtopic :)

Comment: @RoyalBg true indeed : ))